# Passphrase encrypted zfs dataset displays files after zpool import without being mounted

Tags: zfs

I have a zfs pool on Debian with an encrypted dataset that contains other datasets inhering encryption. Basically I have this structure

pool

- passphrase encrypted dataset

  - dataset1 inherits encryption
  - dataset2 inherits encryption

It all behaves exactly as expected except that dataset2 displays its files after zpool import (without loading keys) while being unmounted and key unloaded. Also, while is displays files, they do not contain any information and the size of the dataset is also not real (so, it's clearly not really mounted)

What the heck is going on? The other dataset (dataset1) behaves as expected after zpool import and does not display anything at all.

I'm lost, I thought maybe something got cached strangely but it keeps displaying the files even on a fresh linux installation right after zpool import.

Answer (score 0):

Looks that this has been answered here https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/zfs-encryption-not-working.73409/

The dataset contained database files which was online everytime on reboot before the pool was mounted, so it wrote some stuff under the unencrypted root (pool). Wow, seems kinda clear now.